# WinSCP Session.SynchronizeDirectories removeFiles parameter

Tags: .net, synchronization, winscp

According to [WinSCP documentation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories), if the `removeFiles` parameter is set to true for the `Session.SynchronizeDirectories` method, it will deletes obsolete files.

As the documentation doesn't provide any definition of what an obsolete file is, I had to run some tests to find out what is the impact of the this parameter.

From my understanding, an obsolete file is present on the destination folder but not on the source folder.  So if the `removeFiles` parameter is set to true, any file in the destination folder that can't be matched with a file having same name on the source folder will be deleted.

Do I have the right definition or am I missing something that could impact on the synchronization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is part of the WinSCP documentation (in the [Synchronization Mode section](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full#mode)).

> Files in target directory not present in source directory are optionally deleted (enable option Delete files).

The `option Delete files` is probably refering to the `removeFiles` parameter.

Comment: Option *Delete files* is referring to GUI option. The `removeFiles` parameters in equivalent in WinSCP .NET assembly .